# If $n$ balls (numbered $1 \to n$)are distributed in $n$ bins(numbered).Find the probability that no ball goes into the same numbered bin.

Tags: probability, derangements

I have been thinking about it a lot and my conclusion has been like this :

I found the possible places where the $1$st ball can go, it is $(n-1)$.Then the next ball can go to the bin where the number $1$ ball didn't go. So there will be two possible cases. Suppose that the ball $1$ goes to bin $x$ and if $x \ne 2$ then the second ball can go to $(n-2)$ places. However if $x=2$ then the second ball can go to $(n-1)$ places.

However continuing like this the problem is becoming almost impossible for me to solve. I need some help in this

Comment: Is only one ball permitted in each bin?  If so, you need a derangement of the numbers.  If yes, each ball position is independent.  Please clarify.

Comment: Each bin gets exactly $1$ ball?  Then you're looking for the probability that a randomly selected probability is a "derangement."  You need to count the number of ways something can go wrong, and then use the principle of inclusion and exclusion to account for duplicates.

Comment: Yes only one ball is permitted in each bin

Comment: @Robertshore should I proceed in the way I started.. I don't know because that is becoming too long

Comment: The Wikipedia page on derangements has a nice derivation based on the recurrence.  The probability is very close to $\frac 1e$

Comment: No.  Go backwards.  Figure out how many combinations are "bad" because at least one ball is in a matching bin.  Then subtract those from all possible combinations and you'll know how many derangements there are.  Do you know how to use the principle of inclusion and exclusion?

Comment: please check section _derivation by principle of inclusion exclusion_ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement#:~:text=In%20combinatorial%20mathematics%2C%20a%20derangement,that%20has%20no%20fixed%20points.

Comment: Alternative source, if the problem is about derangements: [Wikipedia-Derangements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement).

Comment: "Yes only one ball is permitted in each bin" Please incorporate this clarification into the body of the question.